# count diff between two dates

Tags: sql

for example

i have two date

start_date = 08:47
end_date = 09:07

i need to group result during half hour, and one moment it is not difference end_date - startdate

it will be 13 minutes in firs half hour interval, and 7 minutes in next interval

08:30 - 09:00   |  13

09:00 - 09:30   |  7

how to calculate it by ms sql?

i know than i need difference 60 minute - start_date, and after end_date - 0 minutes

but how can i do this, if it will be a lot interfals, using cycle?

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _how to calculate it by ms sql_ Do you mean [SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2022) database? If you do, then why did you tag your question "oracle"? And since you also tagged your question "clickhouse", can you explain how it is related to your question?

Comment: it doesn't metter

Comment: @RustyStupidSQL - it does matter, because the approach may be different, and the calculations certainly will (e.g. datediff vs. subtraction). There are already a lot of examples of how to do this sort of thing, so this is probably a duplicate; but even that depends on which database you are actually using.

Comment: As per the linked duplicate, use a recursive sub-query. Like this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EP9qTIkh)

Comment: wow it's super good. can u please show same example to used on clickhouse please